# how to program fpga using SD card

Tags: fpga, u-boot, zynq, bitstream

I'm trying to configure the programmable logic inside the parallella board (based on zynq 7020), I insert an sd card that contains bitstream, fsbl.elf and hello_world.elf after the board is booted I tried to do this

```
zynq-uboot> fatload mmc 0 0x4000000 design_1_wrapper.bit
reading design_1_wrapper.bit

4045678 bytes read
zynq-uboot> fpga loadb 0 0x4000000 4045678
 design filename = "design_1_wrapper;UserID=0XFFFFFFFF;Version=2014.3.1"
 part number = "7z020clg400"
 date = "2015/09/30"
 time = "10:58:34"
 bytes in bitstream = 4045564
Error: Timeout waiting for FPGA to config.
fpga - loadable FPGA image support

Usage:
fpga [operation type] [device number] [image address] [image size]
fpga operations:
 dump [dev] Load device to memory buffer
 info [dev] list known device information
 load [dev] [address] [size] Load device from memory buffer
 loadb [dev] [address] [size] Load device from bitstream buffer (Xilinx only)
 loadmk [dev] [address] Load device generated with mkimage
 For loadmk operating on FIT format uImage address must include
 subimage unit name in the form of addr:<subimg_uname>
zynq-uboot> fpga info 0
Xilinx Device
Descriptor @ 0x3dfb8b84
Family: Zynq PL
Interface type: Device configuration interface (Zynq)
Device Size: 4045564 bytes
Cookie: 0x0 (0)
No Device Function Table.
zynq-uboot>
```

why the PL is not configured? Is it the size?

Thank you

Comment: Might be the FSBL that did not enable the FPGA at all. Why don't you pack your FSBL EFL, bitstream and U-Boot ELF in a boot image?

Comment: You are right I thought of that